# Submitting a Command Buffer DX vs. OpenCL

Tags: directx, opencl

I am wondering if there is a difference between submitting the command buffer in OpenCL vs. DirectX.
As far as I know, submitting the Command Buffer in OpenCL is performed when cFlush or clFinish is called.
Submitting the command buffer in DirectX is explained in [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569747(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569747%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

My question is: are OpenCL and DirectX command buffer submissions conceptually the same?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with DX. But the OpenCL submit system does NOT need clFlush and clFinish in order to run the commands in queue.

Each time a kernel or operation is submitted to a OpenCL queue it is processed as soon as it can asynchronously to the CPU ejecution. 
The clFlush() command just forces the command to enter in the queue. clFinish() ensures that all the jobs have finished in the queue before returning the control to the CPU (it is a blocking call).

For example this will provably work perfectly:

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer()
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()
clEnqueueReadBuffer()
sleep(10)
//continue the processing
```

But the proper way is to check it out by calling clFinish() (ensueres the queue is empty) or by the clEvent subsystem (checks if the queued tasks have been finished):

```
clEnqueueWriteBuffer()
clEnqueueNDRangeKernel()
clEnqueueReadBuffer()
clFinish()
//continue the processing
```

Comment: I appreciate you answer,but it is not related to the question I have asked.My question was about command buffer